# Override the default Rails model template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, generator

I want to override the default model file that's generated with `rails generate model`. I've created a template based on [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb), but I can't figure out where to put it. Other answers seem to suggest `/lib/templates/rails/model/model.rb` or `/lib/templates/rails/model/model_generator.rb`, but neither of those do anything - I put the template in that location but when I run `rails generate model ModelName` it gets ignored.

Am I going about this the right way? Where should I put the template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved: I wanted `lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb`.

Comment: I just had to look up my own old post again to make sure I had the right place. Note to Googlers: if you put your template in the above location and it doesn't seem to be working, make sure you've restarted Spring before running `rails g`.

Comment: or you can also do: `DISABLE_SPRING=true rails g ...`

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to put it in "lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb". Here's the rails' default one: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb

Comment: Does not look right. The [correct location is](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e6b286f9baca7c6c97c90288acdd563c40d5103f/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb#L28) `lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb.tt`, notice the `.tt` at the end, although this is not required.

If overwritten, then pay attention to [the original template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e6b286f9baca7c6c97c90288acdd563c40d5103f/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb.tt).