# Using custom scaffold templates for Rails models and controllers? (`inherited_resources_controller` vs `scaffold controller`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After getting tired of rebuilding all my default scaffold models, views and controllers I decided to create custom templates as outlines on various blogs / SA questions etc.

I created:

```
/lib/templates/active_record/model.rb
/lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb
/lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb.tt (and so on for the actions etc.)
```

I added this to my `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.generators do |g|
      g.orm             :active_record
      g.template_engine :erb
      g.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: true
      g.skip_routes  true
end
```

I then run the scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold MyModel name description notes:text flag_active:boolean slug company_id:integer
Running via Spring preloader in process 52960
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20200130165523_create_my_models.rb
      create    app/models/my_model.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/my_model_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/my_models.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :my_models
      invoke  inherited_resources_controller
      create    app/controllers/my_models_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
      create      app/views/my_models
      create      app/views/my_models/index.html.erb
      create      app/views/my_models/edit.html.erb
      create      app/views/my_models/show.html.erb
      create      app/views/my_models/new.html.erb
      create      app/views/my_models/_form.html.erb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/controllers/my_models_controller_test.rb
      create      test/system/my_models_test.rb
      invoke    helper
      create      app/helpers/my_models_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
      invoke    jbuilder
      create      app/views/my_models/index.json.jbuilder
      create      app/views/my_models/show.json.jbuilder
      create      app/views/my_models/_my_model.json.jbuilder
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/my_models.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/my_models.scss
```

The issues are that the model and controller templates are not used and the views work fine.

I found this post [Scaffolding Rails4 Empty Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624311/scaffolding-rails4-empty-controller) detailing that active admin (which I use) uses `inherited_resources_controller`.  I am guessing that is part of the issue but I am at a loss how to fix this.  I can't seem to find an obvious solution posted anywhere else.

**UPDATE**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906765/1135515

The model template needs to be in:

```
/lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb
```

And the controller template needs to be:

```
/lib/templates/rails/inherited_resources_controller/controller.rb
```

My updated question would be then why is rails using `inherited_resources_controller` vs `scaffold controller` and can I fix that?

Comment: I stumbled on half of the solution - if I put my controller template in `inherited_resources_controller` that seems to fix the controller template issue.

Answer (score 0):

Covered by:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/14-gotchas.md#rails-5-scaffold-generators

and

https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/issues/195

In short something like this:

```
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_controller :scaffold_controller
end
```